# How to determine authentication method while using Google Cloud Platform client libraries locally

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-python, vision-api

I'm currently able to run a local python script that calls the Google vision API using the [python client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) (specifically, I'm using the `google-cloud-vision` package).  However, I'm curious about how it's authenticating.  In the python script that I'm running locally I do not provide any authentication information.  From reading the below posts, it seems that a common way to authenticate when running locally is to set an environment variable to the path of a .JSON key file (i.e `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = path/to/JSON/key/file`), however, I don't recall doing this and if I run `printenv`, I do not have an environment variable called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

The below posts provide great details about different ways to authenticate using the client libraries locally, but **how can I see/determine exactly how my program is being authenticated?  Is there a way to query for this?**

["Authenticating to the Cloud Vision API"](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth#top_of_page)...including the ["Application Default Credentials"](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth#application_default_credentials) part of the above page

["Authenticating Applications With a Client Library"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances?hl=en_US&_ga=2.257948290.-809205911.1510850812&_gac=1.170601876.1516657719.EAIaIQobChMIh-WMosbs2AIVh7fACh1PGwf9EAAYASAAEgLwRvD_BwE#clientlib) section of Creating and Enabling Service Accounts for Instances

["Providing Credentials to Your Application"](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) section of "Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Capabilities" page

["Setting the Environment Variable"](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) Section of "Getting Started With Authentication" page:

Python client libraries ["Getting Started"](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started) page:

["Authenticating to a Cloud API Service"](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth#top_of_page)

Answer (score 4):

There's 4 different ways for the request to be authenticated without creating a [credentials object](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html#explicit-credentials).

1. If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set to the path of a valid service account JSON private key file, then it is used.
2. If the Google Cloud SDK is installed and has [application default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) set then it is used. Note that if you've done this step once in the past, it will stay valid. *(I'm guessing that this is what you're currently using to authenticate.)*
3. If the application is running in the App Engine Standard environment then the credentials and project ID from the App Identity Service are used. *(Not applicable here but I'm listing it for completeness' sake.)*
4. If the application is running in Compute Engine or the App Engine flexible environment then the credentials and project ID are obtained from the Metadata Service. *(Not applicable here but I'm listing it as well for completeness' sake.)*

If no credentials are found using the methods above, DefaultCredentialsError will be raised. Since you're not getting this error, and you don't have the environment variable from #1 set, and options #3 & #4 are not applicable, the only option that remains is number #2.

The above information can be found on the [readthedocs.io page for the google-cloud Authentication page](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html), and more specifically in the [google.auth package page](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default)

You can check if you have the application default credentials set up by running this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token):

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

If this doesn't return an error but an access token, it means that #2 is set up. **Don't share this token with anyone of course...**

Some related information, you can check the token that was printed out with the command above [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/oauth2/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo), or using the curl command below (paste the token at the end):

```
curl -i https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=
```

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but by process of elimination it should be the correct one...

Comment: is there still no way to actually display which auth is being used rather than just guessing/by elimination?

Comment: not AFAIK, but this is not something you should care about. If you do care, use #1 explicitly. It will be used before #2.

Comment: actually the better way is to set up explicit authentication inside your code, as per [auth docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code)